# How to make child element not expand a sibling div in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

So I have some code that I'm supposed to edit.

I'm including some example code here, this is roughly how it looks.

```
<div class="wraparound">
    <div class="clickable">
        <p>Text</p>
        <a href="">Floated Button</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

My issue is as follows. When you click the "floated button", the jquery will still open the sibling divs inside of the wraparound divider, for like a split second before the user is sent to the Floated Button link.

How do I make the button NOT open those divs when it's clicked, even when it's inside the clickable div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could stop propagation of the event when the link is clicked:

```
$('.clickable a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: I was thinking about using stopPropagation, but I was afraid it might disrupt the link actually firing and sending the user.

Comment: Nope, `return false;` or `e.preventDefault()` would stop the browser from following the link, but `stopPropagation` should not.